# Does GeForce RTX 4080 would solve these issues against Radeon RX 6800XT?

Tags: graphics-cards, gaming, linux, windows, ubuntu

I've just bought a new PC with the following specs:

- AMD Ryzen 9 7950X 16 Core
- GIGABYTE X670E AORUS MASTER
- DDR5 Corsair VENGEANCE 5200 MHz 32 GB
- AMD Radeon RX 6800XT

I have a dual boot with Ubuntu 23.04 and Windows 11.
In both OS I have problems with, I guess, the GPU. In other forums I asked about the drivers and made a lot of tests.

My main needs are about two applications: Blender in Linux and Microsoft Flight Simulator in Windows.

For Blender, in order to enable Cycles there are 3 options for nvidia graphic cards (CUDA, OptiX and oneAPI) while only 1 for radeon ones (HIP).

**First question**: does this mean a GeForce would be more compatible? It's hard to enable HIP in Linux and after installing the AMD drivers I got my system unstable.

For MSFS I cannot run the program at all. It always crashes to desktop, no matter how many "workaround" I tried.

**Second question**: I read somewhere even for the games nvidia would be better. Do you thing is it true?

Feel free to ask any other information you may need or to suggest any other option.

Answer (score 2):

Since your use case prefers CUDA Nvidia GPU's are always the best option, although the Linux drivers are kinda bad. Nvidia is not faster in games, but since the 4080 is 1 gen newer than the 6800XT, it will be faster in almost every situation. If you have trouble getting the Nvidia drivers to work with Linux, I have heard the Windows drivers are better (and I normally don't reccomend that but since you already have bought Windows you can give it a try)

Also for MSFS, have you tried installing the AMD drivers? As a Linux user, I just forget about it since MESA is generally already built into the kernel, but that is not the case on Windows, so you have to install drivers (both with Nvidia and AMD)

Comment: Linux: it is my primary OS and I use it for almost everything (but gaming), so I strongly hope I can find the right drivers for Nvidia. MFSF: yes, I installed the AMD drivers (at least 5 different versions).

Comment: In that case, I don't know if going nvidia will fix MSFS, but it should at least fix Blender if you get the drivers to work